# Is there a way to get Visio Shape Name using Shape.get_Cells("") method

Tags: c#, .net, visio

I'm trying to get Visio shape name. Shape.Name doesn't meant for exact name of a shape. So now i'm trying to get shape using any method/API. It's not an exact string `User.UMLShapeName`, But trying something like this.

```
if (shape.get_CellExistsU("User.UMLObjectGUID", 1) != 0)      
    string Sname = shape.get_Cells("User.UMLShapeName").Formula;
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  You seem to be checking for the existence of one cell before accessing another?  Can you give more details in your question?  Also, are you dealing with a specific master / stencil / template (if so which one) or a custom one?

Comment: I'm just want to retrieve name of the Visio shape. I have no idea what string should be used in 'get_Cells("String")'. For example: string UMLGuid = shape.get_Cells("User.UMLObjectGUID").Formula; is used to get shape GUID value.

Comment: A shape has two names Shape.Name and Shape.NameU.  There's no cell for this - it's a direct property of the Shape class.  The local name (Name) is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767617.aspx and the universal name (NameU) is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765535.aspx.  You might also want to look at the UniqueID property, but take a look at some background here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa201761(v=office.10).aspx#_#783